# How to paste range of columns (say A to F) excluding certain columns (D) in email body using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have this below code which works for a continuous range of columns from A to F.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim StrBody As String


StrBody =  "Find the table below"

Set Rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

 Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A01:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

    .To = ""
    .cc = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Test"
    .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(Rng)
    .Display 
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing 
End Sub
```

However I now want to exclude column D from the range so the new range would be A01:C10 and E01:F10.
Here is my RangetoHTML function,

```
Function RangetoHTML(Rng As Range)

Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
Rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

I tried changing the Rng value as below but nothing appears if I make this change in the outlook mail box,

```
Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A01:C10,E01:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Please help me!

Comment: I tested your code with the `A1:C10,E1:F10` range, and it works for me

Answer (score 0):

*Try hiding `.Columns("D:D")` before `Set = Rng`*

*Example*

> ```
> With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
>     .Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
> End With
>
> Set Rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A01:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
> ```

*Or this*

> ```
> With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
>     .Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
>
>     Set Rng = .Range("A01:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
>
>    .Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
> End With
> ```

Comment: Hi the above code successfully hides the column but when the column is hidden the mail body is empty, it's not pulling anything into outlook mail body.

Comment: I have added the code you mentioned in the below area of the routine.

Set Rng = Nothing
On Error Resume Next

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    Set Rng = .Range("A01:F10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

   .Columns("D:D").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
End With

On Error GoTo 0

If Rng Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
           vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If

Comment: Sorry for the formatting above, to be precise I have added the code you mentioned exactly in the place where I am declaring the Rng variable in the routine. After doing that and clicking mail button the body of the mail is empty.

Comment: @varun are still having issue- would you like me to post full code?

Comment: @varun  if you feel this answer was useful to you feel free to mark it as answer, thanks - see how to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not saving the workbook before closing; so, it's probably be easiest to delete the ranges that you do not want before copying.

```
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: I can not delete the column cause it should be present after the mailing. Do you mean you can undo the delete using code?

Comment: Also delete would change the format of other data in my excel sheet, so delete is not an option for me.